# Group operation used in decomposition of Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

As I was taught, any finite abelian group $G$ can be represented up to isomorphism by a direct product of cyclic integer groups of prime power (there is some canonical fuss there, but that's only by convention). So then, one can write:
$$G\sim \mathbb{Z}_{p_1}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p_2}\times\dots\times\mathbb{Z}_{p_n}$$

Now, [on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Classification) about abelian groups, I have two things confusing me.

The first is that they sometimes write $\mathbb{Z}_{p_1}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p_2}$, and other times $\mathbb{Z}_{p_1}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p_2}$. I don't know whether that's a matter of notation, or that it has actual meaning (e.g. having addition vs. multiplication in the end result or in the individual factors). I was taught using $\times$ only.

Secondly, it is stated that:

> For another example, every abelian group of order $8$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb {Z} _{8}$ (the integers $0$ to $7$ under addition modulo $8$), $\mathbb {Z}_{4}\oplus \mathbb {Z} _{2}$ (the odd integers $1$ to $15$ under multiplication modulo $16$), or $\mathbb {Z} _{2}\oplus \mathbb {Z}_{2}\oplus \mathbb {Z} _{2}$.

I take it that whatever is in parentheses is an example of such a group. However, how do I know which group operation is used in the factors of these decompositions, and in the end result? Neither the page nor my Abstract Algebra textbook mentions this explicitly, as far as I can tell. However, there is a big difference between $\langle\mathbb{Z}_p, +\rangle$ and $\langle\mathbb{Z}_p, \cdot\rangle$:

1. For one, we don't actually consider the $0$ in $\langle\mathbb{Z}_p, \cdot\rangle$ to be part of the group, making it (or, if you will, the multiplicative group inside it) of order $p-1$ instead of $p$; there can't be a bijection between two finite groups of unequal order, so this would change the isomorphism the theorem says there is.
2. For two, all $\langle\mathbb{Z}_n, +\rangle$, regardless of $n$ (generated by $1$) are cyclic. This is the case for $\langle\mathbb{Z}_p, \cdot\rangle$ if $p$ is prime, but canonically, we have structures like $\mathbb{Z}_4$ appear in the decomposition, which is not cyclic under multiplication. This also affects any isomorphism.

Which operations are used for the factors and in the result, and am I correct that they matter after all?

Comment: Yes, so in fact ${\mathbb Z}_p$ is not a group under multiplication. So the operation on ${\mathbb Z}_p$ cannot be multiplication can it? So it has to be addition. Personally I think ${\mathbb Z}_p$ is a very bad notation and appears to cause a lot  of unnecessary confusion. It can be used to mean an additive group or a ring of order $p$, or the ring of $p$-adic integers. I use $C_n$ as a general notation for a cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Well, I agree, but it wouldn't be the first time someone used "the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p$" or "$\langle\mathbb{Z}_p,\cdot\rangle$" to imply $\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{0\}$ with multiplication mod $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct product and the direct sum always coincide on finite abelian groups, so you can use either.

About your second question: the examples inside the brackets actually tell you what the operation is. For $\mathbb{Z}_8$ it says "addition modulo 8". Indeed, you can verify that $1$ is a generator (as $n=1+1+...+1$, $n$ times) and therefore that group is cyclic of order $8$.

If you meant "how do I know in the general case", when you are given an abelian group you are given elements and a group operation. Every subgroup that appears in the decomposition inherits that group operation, so there is no ambiguity.

Many cyclic groups can be realised as additive groups $(\mathbb{Z}_p, +)$ and also as multiplicative groups $(\mathbb{Z}_q^\times, \cdot)$. This is not a contradiction, as the group operation does not distinguish between $+$ and $\cdot$ when you consider the factors just up to isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I understand $+$ and $\cdot$ being interchangeable quite yet: if I have $\mathbb{Z}_8$ in a decomposition (let's say an abelian group of order 32), then shouldn't it matter that the product $G\sim\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ exhibits different modular behaviour in case the factors are additive vs. multiplicative groups (and so $G$ is as well), due to 8 and 4 not being coprime in this example? Or is it perhaps true that when $G$ changes its operation, we _want_ the possible products to have different modular behaviour?

Comment: I'll be more explicit: the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a cyclic group of order $6$, generated by $3$. So $(\mathbb{Z}_7, \cdot) \cong (\mathbb{Z}_6, +)$.

So when given an abelian group $G$ that you want to decompose if it happens to have such a factor, for instance $G=(\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_8, +)$, you can write $$G=(\mathbb{Z}_7, \cdot) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}_8, +)$$ or $$G=(\mathbb{Z}_6, +) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}_8, +)$$ and they're both correct, as they are isomorphic groups!

Comment: Okay, that clears it up almost entirely. Let me verify: in my professor's textbook, the possible decompositions of abelian groups $G$ of order $<20$ are given. Very notably, the product of the factor orders is the order of $G$ each time: e.g., it says for a $G$ of order $12$: $G\sim\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ or $G\sim\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{6}$, and for order $18$, it's $18$ or $3\times 6$. Would that mean the textbook assumes $+$? Otherwise, $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ secretly denotes $\langle(\mathbb{Z}_{12})_0,\cdot\rangle$, which is of prime order $11$ (which can't be factored). Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. In group theory you often write $C_n$ for the cyclic group of order $n$, and sometimes people write $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for the same group as well, since integers mod $n$ always form a cyclic group under addition.

Comment: And, to be precise (most people are) when the group is multiplicative the set of elements should not be $\mathbb{Z}_n$ but $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$, i.e. only the invertible elements. For instance, $0$ is never an element in the multiplicative group, and when $n$ is not prime there are other noninvertible elements. For instance $(\mathbb{Z}_4^\times, \cdot) \cong C_2$.